# How to calculate difference between 2 times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns in a table i.e. `DutyHours(time(7))` and `TimeSpentInOffice(time(7))`.

How can I calculate the difference between these two times?

The `datediff` function returns in hour, minute, second or day etc but not in time.

Comment: What do you expect when you like to have the result in "time"?

Comment: There is no `TimeSpan` datatype in TSQL.

Comment: for example if duty time is 09:00:00 .i.e. nine hours and his officestay time is 08:00:00 i.e. 8 hours, i want output as 01:00:00 .i.e 1 hour( means he stay 1 hour less then the duty time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @null time;
SET @null = '00:00:00';

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, End_Time, Start_Time), @null)
```

Reference: [Time Difference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a259b55-a2aa-4c3c-a73d-afa44d455f5c/difference-between-2-time-columns-in-sql-server-2008?forum=transactsql)

**Edit:** As per the comment, if the difference between the end time and the start time might be negative, then you need to use a `case` statement as such

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, End_Time, Start_Time) <=0
           THEN DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, End_Time, Start_Time), @null)
           WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, End_Time, Start_Time) >0
           THEN DATEADD(SECOND,  DATEDIFF(SECOND, End_Time, Start_Time), @null)
       END AS TimeDifference
```

Comment: And if the difference is negative 1 hour? This would return '23:00'.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, I updated my answer to accommodate this scenario.

Comment: for example if duty time is 09:00:00 .i.e. nine hours and his office stay time is 08:00:00 i.e. 8 hours, i want output as 01:00:00 .i.e 1 hour( means he stay 1 hour less then the duty time).

Comment: @Vikky and this is exactly what this solution is giving to you. just replace end_time with dutytime and the start time with the officetime.